# Logic for Gold, Silver, Bronze

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm building a game in javascript and have my results generated.

```
var score = array("5", "5", "1");
```

So player 1 has a score of 5, player 2 a score of 5 and player 3 a score of 1.

I want to display my results as 3 levels - Gold, Silver and Bronze, however if the top two results are the same I want them both to be gold, leaving the lowest score silver.

What is the best way to work this out using javascript?

Ideally my results array for this particular set of scores would look like this:

```
var results = array("gold", "gold", "silver");
```

Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't you want your results in your example to be "Gold", "Gold", " Bronze"?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. This is why I am having difficulty.

Comment: @jzd: This could go an assortman of ways. I believe in lieu of there being three scores but only two awards to give out, it goes next-highest. Though it's more common for a tie in a spot to share the lesser-badge, but to each his own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code doing it:

```
var scores = [5, 8, 1];
scores.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (a > b) ? 1 : ((a < b) ? -1 : 0);
}).reverse();
var medals = {};
var medalsUsed = 0;
var availableMedals = ['Gold', 'Silver', 'Bronze'];
for(var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
    var score = scores[i];
    var medal;
    if(medals[score]) { // already have a medal for this score value? use it
        medal = medals[score];
    }
    else { // use next available medal
        if(i >= 3) return; // but not if we've already given out 3 medals
        medal = availableMedals.shift();
        medals[score] = medal;
    }

    alert('medal for ' + i + ': ' + medal);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ASdb8/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ASdb8/5/ : won't work, indexes are strings, so they sort wrong.

Comment: I don't know if that sort method will always return the array of integers sorted due to the lexicographical nature of Javascript's sort...

Comment: nope: i mean in your code, not his, check the fiddle I linked, medals[score] fails on [5,25,10] 25 is higher index than 5 (even when it is a number

Comment: Changed it to sort by number, not by whatever is JS's default.

Comment: I also found a bug with it returning, in some instances, 4 metals. ;-\ (just try this a couple times: http://jsfiddle.net/ASdb8/7/ [note I added the actual score as an output]) _this appears to be when the third-level score is a duplicate, e.g. [1,2,3,3]_

Comment: IMO that's correct. How would you determine who gets bronze if there are 2 people who have equal score?

Comment: I suppose you're right in cases of a tie. I just didn't expect the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

I would first sort the array then compare values (1 with 2 and 2 with 3).  To sort an array of numbers you need to pass the sort function another function as an argument.

```
var medals = ['Gold', 'Silver', 'Bronze']; 

score = score.sort(compare);

//Return descending order
function compare(a,b){
    return b-a;
}

results[0] = medals.shift();
//I'm assuming you only want top 3  scores    
for(var i = 1; i < 3; i++){
    if(score[i] == score[i-1]){
        results[i] = results[i-1];
    }else{
        results[i] = medals.shift();
    }
}
```

This code sorts the scores, and if any of them are equal sets the medal to be the same as the one before it.

Proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/Fttmj/1/

Comment: This will give out two Golds and one Bronze, but the question requires two Golds and one Silver when the top score is tied.

Comment: No it won't. Look, if the scores are equal then the results array equals whatever was in the previous results index. It only takes the next medal when the next score is less than the previous. In fact, here's a fiddle to prove it: http://jsfiddle.net/Fttmj/1/

Answer (score 0):

First loop through the array and determine the highest and the next two highest scores.

Then loop through your player scores and assign "Gold" to any score that matches the highest score, "Silver" to any score that matches the second highest, and "Bronze" to any score that matches the third highest score.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is using Javascript's max() function, then comparing the gold/silver and the bronze/silver scores. if gold and silver equal, change silver to gold and bronze to silver, and if the silver and bronze are equal change the bronze to silver.

Answer (score 0):

yet another method

```
var results = ['Gold', 'Silver', 'Bronze'];
var arr = [5, 5, 5];
arr.sort().reverse();
var currentScore = arr[0];
var idx = 0;
for(var i=0; i< arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i]!= currentScore){
        idx++;
        currentScore = arr[i];
    }
    alert(arr[i]+ ' has ' + results[idx] + ' medal');
}
```

update: [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/3p2Kx/)